# Contract address payable issue

Tags: erc-20, payable, receive

If i remove `payable` from: [image]
then i get this error with my `receive` function. Not sure how to fix this. I have an erc20 token contract that has a receive function and this contract inherits from it, that's why it has override. Another thing to note is that the erc20 contract also has the same problem with delcaring `address(this)` to a payable address with a receive function.

[image]

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.7.0;

import "./lib/Permissioned.sol";
import "./interfaces/ICredits.sol";

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
//
//                      (c) The BotNet Project 2020
//
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

// TO DO...
// [ ] ADD PERMISSION MODIFIER W/ "hasAccess" bool variable -> ONLY OBTAINABLE VIA DEPLOYER CONFIRMATION 
// [ ] MAKE APPROVE FUNCTION THAT CONTRACTS WITH PERMISSION CAN ACCESS 

contract Credits is ICredits, Permissioned {
    using SafeMath for uint256;

//  ----------------------------------------------------
//               Variables + Constructor
//  ----------------------------------------------------

    string _name = "Credits";
    string _symbol = "CRDTS";
    uint8 _decimals = 18;                       
    uint256 public initialCreditsSupply = 20000000 * 10**uint(_decimals);         // 20,000,000 credits supply upon deployment
    uint256 private totalCreditsSupply;                                           // Credits' total supply (can be adjusted)
    uint256 public totalCreditsHeld;                                              // how many Credits are in custody of users
    uint256 public remainingUnheldCredits;                                        // amount of credits that aren't owned
    address payable creditsContract;                                              // the address that holds the total supply

    constructor() {    
        isPaused = false;                                                  // contract is unpaused on deployment
        creditsContract = address(this);                                   // creditsContract = this contract address (Credits.sol)    
        users[creditsContract].hasContractAccess = true;                   // is given contract access for contractApprove()
        totalCreditsSupply = initialCreditsSupply;                         // total credits supply = total inital credits supply
        totalCreditsHeld = 0;                                              // credits held by users = 0
        users[creditsContract].creditBalance = totalCreditsSupply;         // creditsContract owns total supply
        remainingUnheldCredits = users[creditsContract].creditBalance;     // amount of credits that aren't owned = total supply
    }

//  ----------------------------------------------------
//                   View Functions 
//  ----------------------------------------------------

    function symbol() override external view returns (string memory) {
        return _symbol;
    }
    function name() override external view returns (string memory) {
        return _name;
    }
    function decimals() override external view returns (uint8) {
        return _decimals;
    }
    function totalSupply() override external view returns (uint) {
        return totalCreditsSupply;  
    }
    function balanceOf(address tokenOwner) override external view returns (uint creditBalance) {
        return users[tokenOwner].creditBalance;
    }

//  ----------------------------------------------------
//                User Transfer Functions 
//  ----------------------------------------------------

    function transfer(address _to, uint _amount) override external pauseFunction returns (bool success) {
        require(users[msg.sender].creditBalance >= _amount, "insufficient funds, revert");
        _transfer(msg.sender, _to, _amount);
        return true;
    }
    
    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint _amount) override external pauseFunction returns (bool success) {
        require(users[_from].creditBalance >= _amount, "from address has insufficient funds, revert");
        require(users[msg.sender].allowance[_from] >= _amount, "insufficient allowance, revert");
        require(users[msg.sender].allowance[_from] <= users[_from].creditBalance);
        users[msg.sender].allowance[_from] = users[msg.sender].allowance[_from].sub(_amount);
        _transfer(_from, _to, _amount);
        return true;
    }

    function _transfer(address _from, address _to, uint256 _amount) private pauseFunction {
        if(_from == creditsContract) {
            users[_from].creditBalance = users[_from].creditBalance.sub(_amount);
            users[_to].creditBalance = users[_to].creditBalance.add(_amount);
            remainingUnheldCredits = users[owner].creditBalance;
            totalCreditsHeld = totalCreditsSupply.add(remainingUnheldCredits);
        } else if (_to == creditsContract){
            users[_from].creditBalance = users[_from].creditBalance.sub(_amount);
            users[_to].creditBalance = users[_to].creditBalance.add(_amount);
            remainingUnheldCredits = users[owner].creditBalance;
            totalCreditsHeld = totalCreditsSupply.sub(remainingUnheldCredits);
        } else {
            users[_from].creditBalance = users[_from].creditBalance.sub(_amount);
            users[_to].creditBalance = users[_to].creditBalance.add(_amount);
        }
        emit Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _amount);
    }

//  ----------------------------------------------------
//               User Approve + Allowance 
//  ----------------------------------------------------

    function contractApprove(address _approver, address _approvee, uint256 _amount) contractAccess external returns (bool success) {
        _approve(_approver, _approvee, _amount);
        return true;
    }

    function approve(address _spender, uint _amount) override external pauseFunction returns (bool success) {
        // require(msg.sender != creditsContract, "ERROR: Unable to set ");
        _approve(msg.sender, _spender, _amount);
        return true;
    }

    function _approve(address _owner, address _spender, uint _amount) private {
        users[_owner].allowance[_spender] = _amount;
        emit Approval(_owner, _spender, _amount);
    }

    function viewAllowance(address tokenOwner, address spender) override external pauseFunction view returns (uint remaining) {
        return users[tokenOwner].allowance[spender];
    }

//  ----------------------------------------------------
//                 Mint + Burn Credits 
//  ----------------------------------------------------

    function generateCredits(uint _amount) override external onlyOwner returns (bool success) {
        users[creditsContract].creditBalance = users[creditsContract].creditBalance.add(_amount);
        totalCreditsSupply = totalCreditsSupply.add(_amount);
        remainingUnheldCredits = users[owner].creditBalance;              
        emit generatedCredits(totalCreditsSupply, creditsContract, _amount);
        return true;
    }
    function deleteCredits(uint _amount) override external onlyOwner returns (bool success) {
        require(users[creditsContract].creditBalance >= _amount);
        users[creditsContract].creditBalance = users[creditsContract].creditBalance.sub(_amount);
        totalCreditsSupply = totalCreditsSupply.sub(_amount);
        remainingUnheldCredits = users[creditsContract].creditBalance;    
        emit deletedCredits(totalCreditsSupply, _amount);
        return true;
    }

    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //                          Don't accept ETH
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    receive () virtual external payable {
        revert();
    }
}
```

Note: I was in the middle of changing names of variables, etc so don't mind them. It should be unrelated to the receive function , I think.

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.7.0;

import "./Credits.sol";

/// @title Inital Token Offering (ITO)
/// @dev ITO is the contract for managing the Credits' crowdsale
// allowing investors to purchase Credits for Ether. 

// TO DO...
// [X] MAKE INTO A SLOW DRIP INSTEAD OF EVERYONE GETS AT ONCE (i.e. 25% at the start of each month for 4 months)
// [X] MAKE TOKENS CLAIMABLE FOR CREDITS  
// [ ] MAKE MODIFIER "SOLD OUT" FOR REMAINING CREDIBYTES REMAINING, THAT ARE ABLE TO BE PURCHASED
// [ ] MAKE A CREDITS TOTAL SUPPLY 
// [ ] FIX TRANSFERFROM & TRANSFER FUNCTION SO DEVS CANT DRAIN SUPPLY

contract CreditsITO is Credits {
  using SafeMath for uint256;

  Credits credits;                                      // The token being sold

  uint256 public conversionRate_EthToCredits;        // How many credibytes a buyer gets per eth.
  uint256 public totalEthRaised;                        // Amount of eth raised
  uint256 public minEthRequirement;                     // minimum amount of eth required to buy credibytes

  address itoContract = address(this);          // the address that holds the credits total supply
  uint256 public remaining_itoCreditsSupply;             // the remaining credibytes that are available for purchase

  uint256 public itoTotalParticipants;                  // the amount of ito user participants 
    
    
  event CredibytesPurchase(                             // Event for credibytes purchase logging
    address indexed purchaser,                          // who paid for the credits
    address indexed beneficiary,                        // who received the credits
    uint256 ethAmount,                                  // ethers paid for credits
    uint256 credibyteAmount                             // amount of credits purchased
  );
  event CredibytesRedemption(                           // Event for credibytes redemption
    address indexed redeemer,                           // user redeeming
    uint256 indexed creditsAmount,                      // amount of credits getting redeemed from credibytes
    uint256 time                                        // time of redemption
  );    
  event developerEthWithdrawal(                         // event for developer withdrawing eth
    address indexed to,                                 // address the developer is sending the eth to
    uint256 indexed amount,                             // the amount of eth being sent
    uint256 indexed timeOfWithdrawal                    // the block timestamp of the withdrawal
  );
  event ethDepositToDeveloper(                          // event for developer receiving eth
    address indexed from,                               // address that sent the eth
    uint256 indexed amount,                             // the amount of eth being sent
    uint256 indexed timeOfDeposit                       // the block timestamp of the deposit
  );
  event developerCreditsWithdrawal(                     // event for developer withdrawing credits (helps users prepare for a dump if need be)
    address indexed to,                                 // the address receiving the credits
    uint256 indexed amount,                             // the amount of credits being withdrawn
    uint256 indexed timeOfWithdrawal                    // the block timestamp of the withdrawal
  );

  constructor() {
    deploymentDate = block.timestamp;
    timelockActivationDate = deploymentDate + 4 weeks;
    hasFinalised = false;
    conversionRate_EthToCredits = 10000;
    minEthRequirement = 1 ether;                                                // the minimum amount required to purchase credibytes
    
    users[itoContract].hasContractAccess = true;                                // is given contract access for contractApprove()
    remaining_itoCreditsSupply = 85000000;                                       // 8,500,000 credits available
  }


//  ----------------------------------------------------
//                      Dashboard 
//  ----------------------------------------------------

  /// @notice Allows owner to update the eth to credibytes conversion rate.
  /// @param _newRate new eth to credibytes conversion rate.
  function setRate_EthToCredits(uint _newRate) public onlyOwner {
    conversionRate_EthToCredits = _newRate;
  }

  /// @notice Allows owner to update the minimum amount of eth to partake in the ITO.
  /// @param _newMinimumRequirement the new minimum amount of eth to partake in the ITO.
  function updateMinimumRequirement(uint _newMinimumRequirement) public onlyOwner {
      minEthRequirement = _newMinimumRequirement;
  }

  function finalise() public onlyOwner {    // Allows owner to finish the ITO before the timelock.
    hasFinalised = true;
  }



//  ----------------------------------------------------
//                      ITO Timelock 
//  ----------------------------------------------------

  uint256 public deploymentDate;              // The block when the timer begins counting from.
  uint256 public timelockActivationDate;      // The block when the contract locks/stops functioning.

  bool public hasFinalised;

  // If: now <= timelockActivationDate, continue functionality of ITO.
  modifier ito_Timelock {
    require(
        block.timestamp <= timelockActivationDate || hasFinalised != true, 
        "ERROR: ITO phase is over: contract locked & no longer functional."
      );
    _;
  }
  
  // Allows the 
  modifier canRedeem {
    require(
        block.timestamp >= timelockActivationDate || hasFinalised == true, 
        "ERROR: ITO phase is currently underway: can redeem once finalised or timelock has activated."
      );
    _;
  }


//  ----------------------------------------------------
//         Developer Funds Functions + Timelock
//  ----------------------------------------------------

  // Prevents developer(s) from withdrawing credits instantly after the ito has finished
  modifier creditsTimeLock {
    require(
      timelockActivationDate >= timelockActivationDate + 26 weeks, 
      "ERROR: Wait until timelock period is over to access functionality."
      );
    _;
  }

  // Allows users to view when the dev. timelock is over
  function viewTimeLockStatus() external view returns (
      uint256 timelockCommenced, 
      uint256 timelockCompletition, 
      uint256 timeRemaining
    ) { 
    return (
      timelockActivationDate,
      timelockActivationDate + 26 weeks,
      (timelockActivationDate + 26 weeks).sub(block.timestamp)
    );
  }

  // Allows the developer to withdraw "x" amount of  the remaining, unsold credits, or send them to the credits contract
  function developerCreditsWithdraw(address _to, uint256 _amount) permissionRequired creditsTimeLock external {
      users[itoContract].creditBalance = users[itoContract].creditBalance.sub(_amount);
      users[_to].creditBalance = users[_to].creditBalance.add(_amount);
      emit developerEthWithdrawal(_to, _amount, block.timestamp);
  } 

  // Allows the developer to withdraw a desired amount of ETH to their desired address
  function developerEthWithdraw(address _to, uint256 _amount) permissionRequired external {
      _to.transfer(_amount);
      emit developerEthWithdrawal(_to, _amount, block.timestamp);
  } 


//  ----------------------------------------------------
//                 External Functions 
//  ----------------------------------------------------

  // Allows the user to conver their credits to credits.
  function redeemCredits() canRedeem public returns (uint256 convertedAmount, bool sucess){
    require(users[msg.sender].credibyteBalance != 0, "ERROR: No credits remaining.");
    uint256 _conversionAmount = validateConversion();                                           // checks how many credits user will receive
    commenceConversion(_conversionAmount);                                                      // transfers credits to user
    emit CredibytesRedemption(msg.sender, _conversionAmount, block.timestamp);
    return (_conversionAmount, true);
  }

  // Transfers eth to designated collector & transfers credits to beneficiary. 
  function buyCredibytes_withETH(address _beneficiary) ito_Timelock public payable {
    uint256 ethAmount = msg.value;                                                              // ethAmount becomes msg.value
    
    _preValidatePurchase(_beneficiary, ethAmount);                                              // validates tx isn't sending 0 wei
    uint256 credibyteAmount = _getCredibyteAmount(ethAmount);                                   // calculates the amount of credits to be created
    
    _forwardFunds(ethAmount);                                                                   // transfers eth to itoCollector
    totalEthRaised = totalEthRaised.add(ethAmount);                                             // updates state: totalEthRaised

    _processPurchase(_beneficiary, credibyteAmount);                                            // transfers credits to beneficiary                       
    emit CredibytesPurchase(msg.sender, _beneficiary, ethAmount, credibyteAmount); 
  }

  // Views the inputted user's credibyte balance
  function viewCredibyeBalance(address user) external view returns (uint256 _credibyteBalance) {
    return users[user].credibyteBalance;
  }

  // Views how many remaining credibytes there are for purchase, with the total eth value of the remaining
  function viewRemainingCredibytesForPurchase() external view returns (
    uint256 remainingCredibytesForPurchase, 
    uint256 ethValueOfRemainingCredibytesForPurchase
    ) {
    return(
      remaining_credibyteSupply,
      remaining_credibyteSupply.div(10000)
    );
  }

  // If unlocked, call buyCredits_forEth || If locked, revert tx.
  receive() override external payable {
    if(block.timestamp <= timelockActivationDate) {
      buyCredibytes_withETH(msg.sender); 
    } else { revert(); }
  }


//  ----------------------------------------------------
//         Redeem Credits Internal Functions 
//  ----------------------------------------------------

  function validateConversion() internal 
    returns(
      uint256 currentCredibyteConversion 
    ) {
    require (
      users[msg.sender].remainingTimeUntilNextConversion <= block.timestamp || users[msg.sender].redemptionCounter == 0,
      "ERROR: Must wait the remaining time until next redeption."
    );
    require (
      users[msg.sender].credibyteBalance != 0,
      "ERROR: Insufficient credibyte balance to redeem."
    );
        if(users[msg.sender].redemptionCounter == 0) {
          users[msg.sender].redemptionCounter = users[msg.sender].redemptionCounter.add(1);       // adds 1 onto the user's current redemption counter
          users[msg.sender].remainingTimeUntilNextConversion = block.timestamp + 4 weeks;         // adds 1 month until user's next redemption activation
          return users[msg.sender].credibyteBalance.div(4);                                       // i.e. balance = 1000, calculates 250
        } 
          else if (users[msg.sender].redemptionCounter == 1) {
            users[msg.sender].redemptionCounter = users[msg.sender].redemptionCounter.add(1);     // adds 1 onto the user's current redemption counter
            users[msg.sender].remainingTimeUntilNextConversion = block.timestamp + 4 weeks;       // adds 1 month until user's next redemption activation
            return users[msg.sender].credibyteBalance.div(3);                                     // i.e. balance = 750, calculates 250 
        } 
          else if (users[msg.sender].redemptionCounter == 2) {
            users[msg.sender].redemptionCounter = users[msg.sender].redemptionCounter.add(1);     // adds 1 onto the user's current redemption counter
            users[msg.sender].remainingTimeUntilNextConversion = block.timestamp + 4 weeks;       // adds 1 month until user's next redemption activation
            return users[msg.sender].credibyteBalance.div(2);                                     // i.e. balance = 500, calculates 250  
        } 
          else if (users[msg.sender].redemptionCounter == 3) {
            users[msg.sender].redemptionCounter = users[msg.sender].redemptionCounter.add(1);     // adds 1 onto the user's current redemption counter
            users[msg.sender].remainingTimeUntilNextConversion = 0;     
            users[msg.sender].fullyConverted = true;
            return users[msg.sender].credibyteBalance;                                            // i.e. balance = 250, calculates remaining       
        }
    }

  function commenceConversion(uint256 _conversionAmount) internal {
    users[msg.sender].credibyteBalance = 0;                                                                  // sets user's credibyte balance to 0
    credits.contractApprove(creditsContract, msg.sender, _conversionAmount);
    credits.transferFrom(creditsContract, msg.sender, _conversionAmount);                                    // transfers credits from to caller
    // users[creditsContract].creditBalance = users[creditsContract].creditBalance.sub(_conversionAmount);   // deducts credits from owner wallet
    // remainingUnheldCredits = users[creditsContract].creditBalance;                                        // updates remaining unheld credits
    // users[msg.sender].creditBalance = users[msg.sender].creditBalance.add(_conversionAmount);             // gives user converted credits amount
    // totalCreditsHeld = totalCreditsSupply.sub(remainingUnheldCredits);                                    // updates total credits held
  }


//  ----------------------------------------------------
//         buyCredits_forETH Internal Functions 
//  ----------------------------------------------------

  function _preValidatePurchase(address _beneficiary, uint256 _ethAmount) ito_Timelock view internal {
    require(
        remaining_credibyteSupply >= (_ethAmount.mul(conversionRate_EthToCredibytes)).div(1000000000000000000), // (1 eth * 10,000)/ 1 eth = 10,000 credibytes
        "ERROR: Insufficent remaining credibyte supply to purchase, check remaining supply and adjust purchase amount."
      );
    require(
        _beneficiary != itoContract && _beneficiary != creditsContract,
        "ERROR: Unable to purchase credibytes for itoContract or creditsContract."
      );
    require(
        _ethAmount >= minEthRequirement, 
        "ERROR: Does not meet the minimum purchasing requirement: refer to minEthRequirement."
      );
  }

  function _getCredibyteAmount(uint256 _ethAmount) ito_Timelock internal view returns (uint256) {
    return (_ethAmount.mul(conversionRate_EthToCredits)).div(1000000000000000000);   // (1 eth * 10,000)/ 1 eth = 10,000 credibytes
  }

  // Transfers eth (msg.value) to developerContract
  function _forwardFunds(uint256 ethAmount) ito_Timelock internal {
    itoContract.transfer(ethAmount);
    emit ethDepositToDeveloper(msg.sender, msg.value, block.timestamp);
  }

  // Calls _deliverTokens.
  function _processPurchase(address _beneficiary, uint256 _credibyteAmount) ito_Timelock internal {
    _deliverCredibytes(_beneficiary, _credibyteAmount);

  }

  // Updates credibyte balance
  function _deliverCreditsRBond(address _beneficiary, uint256 _credibyteAmount) ito_Timelock internal {
    remaining_itoCreditsSupply = remaining_itoCreditsSupply.sub(_credibyteAmount);
    users[_beneficiary].credibyteBalance = users[_beneficiary].credibyteBalance.add(_credibyteAmount);
    if(users[_beneficiary].redemptionCounter != 0 || users[_beneficiary].fullyConverted != false) {
      users[_beneficiary].redemptionCounter = 0;
      users[_beneficiary].fullyConverted = false;
    }
    if(users[_beneficiary].hasParticipatedInITO != true) {                                    // adds users to hasParticipated if they haven't
      users[_beneficiary].hasParticipatedInITO = true;
      itoTotalParticipants = itoTotalParticipants.add(1);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Post the full contact code.

Comment: What solc version are you using?

Comment: The code doesn't compile it is missing Credits contract. Also why does it inherit from Credits and also contains a Credits instance itself? After removing everything not mentioned in the question the code compiles without any issue. Please include a minimal reproducible example it is just guessing otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I think my VS Code is messed up, because I tried using it in remix and it works fine. If anyone knows how to fix this VS Code problem LMK please!